# Check if numerical values in column A are present in the range between 2 numerical values in columns B and C in r

Tags: r, if-statement, range, logic

I want to check if numerical values in column A are present in the range between 2 numerical values in columns B and C in r.

Here is the starting dataset:

```
# dataset with values
numerical_values_dataset <- 
  data.frame(
    A = c("0.798963315", "0.160710819", "0.247170125", "-0.910092611", "0.42959469", "0.710921651", "0.160710819"),
    B = c("0.321418973", "0.710921651", "0.910092611", "0.42959469", "0.42959469", "0.42959469", "0.160710819"),
    C = c("0.812661261", "0.146377668", "0.42959469", "0.710921651", "0.710921651", "0.710921651", "0.160710819")
  )

> numerical_values_dataset
             A           B           C
1  0.798963315 0.321418973 0.812661261
2  0.160710819 0.710921651 0.146377668
3  0.247170125 0.910092611  0.42959469
4 -0.910092611  0.42959469 0.710921651
5   0.42959469  0.42959469 0.710921651
6  0.710921651  0.42959469 0.710921651
7  0.160710819 0.160710819 0.160710819
```

I would at least like to get at least results that correspond to `Ranges_status_yes_no`, and it would be nice to get "Ranges_status_specific".

```
# result Ranges_status_yes_no
Ranges_status_yes_no <- data.frame(Ranges_status_yes_no = c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes"))

# result Ranges_status_specific
numerical_values_dataset$Ranges_status_specific <- c("A is between B and C", "A is between B and C", "A is less than B", "A is less than B", "A is equal to B", "A is equal to C", "A is equal to B and C")

> numerical_values_dataset
             A           B           C Ranges_status_yes_no Ranges_status_specific
1  0.798963315 0.321418973 0.812661261                  yes   A is between B and C
2  0.160710819 0.710921651 0.146377668                  yes   A is between B and C
3  0.247170125 0.910092611  0.42959469                   no       A is less than B
4 -0.910092611  0.42959469 0.710921651                   no       A is less than B
5   0.42959469  0.42959469 0.710921651                  yes        A is equal to B
6  0.710921651  0.42959469 0.710921651                  yes        A is equal to C
7  0.160710819 0.160710819 0.160710819                  yes  A is equal to B and C
```

I suppose one could generate these results using long `ifelse()` statements. But is there a way to do this in some other manner?

Any help, even partial answers, are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
 numerical_values_dataset %>%
       mutate(Ranges_status_specific = case_when(Ranges_status_yes_no == 'no' ~ 'A is less than B',
      
       A <= B & C >= A ~ 'A is between B and C',
       A == 'B' & A != 'C' ~ 'A is equal to B',
       A == 'C' & A != 'B' ~ 'A is equal to 'B',
       TRUE ~ 'A is equal to B and C'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is base R option :

```
transform(
    transform(type.convert(numerical_values_dataset), 
              B = pmin(B, C), C = pmax(B, C)), 
    Ranges_status_yes_no = ifelse(A >= B & A <= C, 'yes', 'no'))

#           A         B         C Ranges_status_yes_no
#1  0.7989633 0.3214190 0.8126613                  yes
#2  0.1607108 0.1463777 0.7109217                  yes
#3  0.2471701 0.4295947 0.9100926                   no
#4 -0.9100926 0.4295947 0.7109217                   no
#5  0.4295947 0.4295947 0.7109217                  yes
#6  0.7109217 0.4295947 0.7109217                  yes
#7  0.1607108 0.1607108 0.1607108                  yes
```